# Silverlight application loading stops

Tags: silverlight-5.0

Most of times Silverlight application stops loading. 
Very few times only its successfully loads the application in browser.

Loading stops everytime at different percentage. Some times stops at 2 percentage other times it goes upto 40 or 50 percentage then stops.

This issue happens when I try to load the application from webserver. but its working when I put it in localhost(IIS).